# What is the format of win64?

Tags: object-files

What is the format of the `win64` format produced by `nasm -f win64`?
This program:

```
    extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ExitProcess
section .bss
    dummy resd 1
section .data
    msg db "abc"
    msglen equ $ - msg
section .text
_start:
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, msg
    mov r8, msglen
    mov r9, dummy
    push NULL
    call WriteConsoleA

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess

NULL equ 0
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
```

produces an object file with some things, like the included external functions (`GetStdHandle`, `WriteConsoleA`, and `ExitProcess`), the `abc` string, and variable names (`msg`).

What is the exact format of this? I couldn't find any specification for Win64 online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I saw [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format#general-concepts), I totally did not realize it talked about both the *image file format (PE)* and the **object file format (COFF)**. The object file format is what I'm looking for. Quote:

> This document specifies the structure of executable (image) files and **object files under the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems**. These files are referred to as Portable Executable (PE) and **Common Object File Format (COFF) files**, respectively. The name "Portable Executable" refers to the fact that the format is not architecture specific.

(emphasis mine)